# How do you edit windows 8 app files?

Tags: windows-8, file-permissions

I want to fiddle around with some windows 8 apps on my laptop. I have access to the app files, but when I try to save my changes, a screen pops up that says, "access to the path [path name] is denied." how do I fix this?

Comment: You would have to take ownership of the folder.  Its not advised you do this because it can break other applications.

Answer (score 0):

The folder is `C:\program files\WindowsApps` but as you rightly pointed out - you will get an access denied error.

To fix this, you will need to **double click the folder**.  This will give you a prompt to get **admin approval**.  Click **"Continue**" and it will fail - presenting you with another box.  This box will have a hyperlink in it to go to the **"security tab"**.  **Click that link and this will open a new window**.  Tap the **advanced button** in that window and **change the owner** of the file to yourself.  You can then clode all dialogue boxes.

Once you have done this, go back into the security tab and addd yourself with full control to edit these files.

Word of warning though - this is known to stop apps from working - so tread carefully and only do this if you have a genuine need to do so.